# How do I add this file route to the tsconfig.json properly to get rid of this error?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, tsconfig

Module build failed: Error: (file route) is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

I have found what I thought was the answer here. https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/abp-ng2-module/issues/27
But for some reason it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],

    "types": [
        "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/app/shared/name.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json but even after adding the "files" property I still get the same error.

Comment: did you try include?

Comment: Yes. Both files and include, in both the tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json.

Comment: You may have some misspelling on import. Check this issue- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9523